# Odds of drawing each card from partially known subset of cards

Tags: probability, computational-complexity

Say you have $6$ decks of $52$ suitless cards (so $24$ indistinguishable copies of each rank). From that, you're given a randomly chosen, shuffled subset $S$ of size $52$, of which half of the cards are made known to you (though how these known cards are selected is random, and you don't know how they're ordered or distributed within $S$). Call this group of cards $K$ and call the other cards in $S$ $U$. Then, each card of $S$ is revealed and discarded one at a time. My question is, after having seen $n$ cards revealed and discarded, can you compute the probability of what the $(n+1)th$ revealed card will be without enumerating all the different ways that the revealed cards could have been taken from $K$ and $U$?
Here's a [link](https://github.com/NathanEzraSchmidt/MathExchangeQuestion/blob/master/math_exchange_question.py) to Python script I wrote that solves the problem using such an enumeration.

Comment: The problem is underdefined, based on *how* you're told the 26 cards out of 52. If you're told "the 26 lowest ranks in the 52 cards" (and you know this), the answer will be dramatically different from you're told "the 26 highest ranks in the 52 cards".

Comment: The 26 cards out of the 52  are a randomly selected